# Не ловится исключение в списке асинхронных методов

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность, task, try-catch

Есть форма, при её создании выполняется код:

```cs
public MainForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Test();
}

async Task Test ()
{
  try
  {
    await IAmException();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.ShowMessageBox();
  }
}

async Task<int> IAmException()
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
  return 0;
}
```

Запускаю этот код, всё норм – исключение ловится, показывается сообщение об ошибке. Изменяю его так:

```cs
async Task Test ()
{
  try
  {
    var TaskList = await ExceptionGenerator(1);
    TaskList.ForEach(t => t.Start());
    await Task.WhenAll(TaskList);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.ShowMessageBox();
  }
}

async Task<List<Task<Task<int>>>> ExceptionGenerator(int Size)
{
  var sampleData = new int[Size].FillAndGet(0); //:Заполняет всю матрицу указанным числом
  var tasks = new List<Task<Task<int>>>(Size);
  foreach (var data in sampleData)
  {
    tasks.Add(new Task<Task<int>>(async () => await IAmException(data)));
  }
  return tasks;
}

async Task<int> IAmException(int data)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
  return data;
}
```

Вижу, что срабатывает точка останова в `throw new NotImplementedException();`, продолжить... и всё! catch это исключение почему-то не поймало. Почему исключение улетело в молоко? Я же ожидаю завершения всех тасков внутри try-catch.

Пробовал делать так:

```
async Task Test ()
{
    try
    {
        //(await BenchmarkSites.Passmark.GetAll(_selectedType)).ForEach(h => h.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler.Current));
        var TaskList = (await ExceptionGenerator(1));
        TaskList.ForEach(t => t.Start());
        var waitAll = Task.WhenAll(TaskList);
        await waitAll;
        waitAll.Exception?.ShowMessageBox();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.ShowMessageBox();
    }

}
```

При дебаге видно, что `waitAll.Exception` is null

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136814/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы переписал это под делегаты и не мучал конструктор таска.

```
async Task Test()
{
    try
    {
        var delegates = await ExceptionGenerator(1);
        var taskList = delegates.Select(f => Task.Run(f));
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.ShowMessageBox();
    }
}

async Task<List<Func<Task<int>>>> ExceptionGenerator(int Size)
{
    var sampleData = new int[Size]; 
    var tasks = new List<Func<Task<int>>>(Size);
    foreach (var data in sampleData)
    {
        tasks.Add(async () => await IAmException(data));
    }
    return tasks;
}

async Task<int> IAmException(int data)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`TaskList` имеет тип `List<Task<Task<int>>>`.
В этой строке

```
await Task.WhenAll(TaskList);
```

эвейтятся только внешние задачи.

Перепишем эту строку следующим образом:

```
var x = await Task.WhenAll(TaskList);
```

Здесь `x` - `Task<int>[]` - массив задач. Их тоже нужно ожидать.

Добавим их ожидание:

```
await Task.WhenAll(x);
```

Вот теперь код работает.

---

Написано слишком мудрёно. Поэтому код лучше переписать.